# Group by month & year

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to count instances grouped by month & year.

```
SELECT 
    (MONTH(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE)) + ' ' + YEAR(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE))) as Issue_Month,
    COUNT(*) as c
FROM
    (sub query) t1
GROUP BY 
    (MONTH(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE)) + ' ' + YEAR(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE)))
```

> Error line 2:  '+' cannot be applied to bigint, varchar(1)

I have tried swapping `+` for `&` & `||` to build desired string but am having no luck.

---

How do I produce table like below:

```
Month Year  |  c
```

---

How do I produce this table as well:

```
Month  |  Year  |  c
```

Comment: The concatenation operator for Presto is `||` and not `+` (I think).

Comment: I dunno what presto is, but in T-SQL you could just group by month(…), year(…)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`date_format()`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html):

```
SELECT 
    date_format(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE), '%m %Y') as Issue_Month,
    COUNT(*) as c
FROM
    (sub query) t1
GROUP BY 
    date_format(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE), '%m %Y')
```

Comment: Much more intuitive and clean: testing now

Comment: How about ordering this? I tried `ORDER BY` the same expression but it is ordering by months so I have all Jan for the years grouped, and then Feb, and so-on.

Comment: Why don't you format like `%Y '%m'` instead of `'%m %Y'`?

Comment: That worked although it's not intuitive (at least for me. In excel/VBA the format wouldn't matter - the sorting works the same regardless). Clearly still new to SQL. Thanks for answering both questions - I know that's bad newb practice :0

Comment: date_format() returns a string so the sorting is alphanumerical. Excel does a format on the presentation layer, keeping the original value.

Comment: That makes sense. I was expecting date_format() to return a date

Comment: If you want the MMYYYY format you can try this: `GROUP BY date_format(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE), '%m %Y'), date_format(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE), '%Y %m ') ORDER BY date_format(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE), '%Y %m ')` although it's not that efficient and more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is one way to do it to get a single field with `month-year`. Surely this is not the optimal way to accomplish this

```
CONCAT(CAST(MONTH(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE)) as Varchar(2))  , '-' , CAST(YEAR(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE)) as  Varchar(4))) as Issue_Month,
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    (MONTH(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE)) + ' ' + YEAR(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE))) as Issue_Month,
    COUNT(*) as c
FROM
    (sub query) t1
GROUP BY 
    (MONTH(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE)), YEAR(CAST(t1.some_date as DATE)))
```

The grouping clause doesnt need the `bla + bla`. You can just include them the way they are.
btw, because you are not using any other table to base your months on, you will only get months with counts for months which have `Issue`s in them. To overcome this, you could use another table which keeps all months and any data you want to have for each month (Days in it, short form, yearly quarter, holidays, etc.) and left join `Issue_Month` to said table, and `GROUP BY` the main months table.